# What textbook is this chapter from?

Tags: calculus, textbooks

I was looking for a good explanation text on single-variable calculus, especially limits, introduction and examples. I found this [pdf](http://samples.jbpub.com/9780763749651/59957_CH02_CalcCONFIRMING.pdf) and I really like it and would like to read the whole book. I was looking into it, but couldn't find the author or the textbook name.

Does anyone know it?

Comment: It's this one: https://books.google.it/books?id=8yor0HBxarwC&lpg=PA67&ots=pYbdPYdVII&dq=%22Many%20topics%20are%20included%20in%20a%20typical%20course%20in%20calculus%22&pg=PA67#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: http://www.jblearning.com/catalog/9780763759957/preview/

The publishing company is on the bottom. A search of their website easily found their calculus books. They have a preview option and this pdf matches the 4th edition they have showing online.

Comment: @JefferyThompson If you have an answer to the question, then perhaps you could post it as such.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the entire thread is based on links and the question was a bit borderline to begin with. I am glad you got the information you likely thought but down the road it is hard to see how the thread would be useful to other.

Comment: I don't have any objection. I tried to formulate the question in a way that if somebody would be looking for text on limits he could find this thread, so it could have some value for others as well, but I admit that the chance is minimal. I just knew that these communities are well informed and thus the biggest chance to find my answer was here. Would it be more convenient if I deleted the question, @quid?

Comment: Don't worry about it. I think you could not even delete it. Maybe it will be deleted down the road, but anyway it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jefferey Thompson provided this [link](http://www.jblearning.com/catalog/9780763759957/preview/) to Calculus: Early Transcendentals, Fourth Edition.
[Googling this](https://www.google.ca/search?q=Calculus%3A%20Early%20Transcendentals%2C%20Fourth%20Edition) title shows various online purchase options for the various editions.